# A selfish puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

These guys are obviously rich. But how wealthy are these
[top ten richest guys](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/investing/012715/5-richest-people-world.asp) if all their money is taken away?

It turns out this is the list we get:

### (1) Gautam Adani

### (2) Steve Ballmer

### (3) Elon Musk

### (4) Bernard Arnault

### (5) Larry Ellison

### (6) Bill Gates

### (7) Larry Page

### (8) Sergey Brin

### (9) Warren Buffet, Jeff Bezos

---

**Explain how this list was made.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The list was made

> by ordering them by the sum of their roman numeral values (each symbol summed, no subtractions based on position)

*1) Gautam Adani*

> M+D+I = 1000+500+1 = 1501

*(2) Steve Ballmer*

> V+L+L+M = 5+50+50+1000 = 1105

*(3) Elon Musk*

> L+M = 1000+50 = 1050

*(4) Bernard Arnault*

> D+L = 500+50 = 550

*(5) Larry Ellison*

> L+L+L+I = 50+50+50+1 = 151

*(6) Bill Gates*

> I+L+L = 1+50+50 = 101

*(7) Larry Page*

> L = 50

*(8) Sergey Brin*

> I = 1

*(9) Warren Buffet, Jeff Bezos*

> worthless!

Comment: Nice job! And not that it matters ofc, but just a little miss (I forgot it too, at first glance :D) on Steve.

Comment: @Prim3numbah haha small change! but will fix

Comment: @Prim3numbah Fun fact: The Roman Numeral S is actually 1/2, so Jeff Bezos is worth more than Warren Buffet.

Comment: Any idea about the title?

Comment: @CheeseCake Jeff probably won't like this but less than 1 are considered zero in my eyes

Comment: @ACB The title was a reference to the method of solving. "Selfish" as in.. the method of solving revolved around the letters of their names only.